# Would like a late edit reviewed: Law of Demeter

Tags: discussion

I've added a new paragraph (3rd) defining a friend, to [my year old answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/284146/131624)  to a question about The Principle of Least Knowledge or the Law of Demeter.  The answer is already reasonably well received. I'd just like to be sure the added paragraph receives some scrutiny.

Feel free to provide it here.  Not looking for rep so much as wanting the answer to improve as my understanding does.

The answer is a sentimental favorite of mine. My first big hit here. So I'd like to be sure I'm not pulling a George Lucas.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you.  BTW, where were you while this question was earning me the [tumbleweed badge](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/tumbleweed?userid=131624)? :)